# Why are regex URLs specified in Ory Oathkeeper's access rules not being matched?

Tags: json, proxy, yaml, config, ory

I have been using Ory Oathkeeper for a little while, about 2 months ago I had everything working, but now since taking a break and coming back, nothing seems to be working correctly.

I have 3 files, `oathkeeper.yml`,`kratos.json` and `rules.json`. The oathkeeper config has both the kratos and rules files specified correctly, the rule specified in `kratos.json` appears to work correctly, but what's bizarre is that the access rule specified in `rules.json` doesn't work at all. I have confirmed that the access rules for both are being picked up by oatheeper using the CLI command `oathkeeper rules list`.

This leads me to believe that the issue isn't with the rules themselves but with the regex. However, posting the regex rule to an online regex tester like **regexr** shows me that it works correctly. My guess is maybe the .go library used by Oathkeeper could be broken somehow, or that maybe I am doing something wrong in the JSON.

Below are my rules:

```
// kratos.json
[
  {
    "id": "ory:kratos:public",
    "upstream": {
      "preserve_host": true,
      "url": "http://kratos:4433",
      "strip_path": "/.ory/kratos/public"
    },
    "match": {
      "url": "<(http|https):\\/\\/([\\w-]+(\\.[\\w-]+)*|[\\d.]+)(:\\d+)?\\/\\.ory\\/kratos\\/public(\\/.*)?>",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST" ,"PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"]
    },
    "authenticators": [{
      "handler": "noop"
    }],
    "authorizer": {
      "handler": "allow"
    },
    "mutators": [{
      "handler": "noop"
    }]
  }
]
```

```
// rules.json
[
  {
    "id": "fusion:account:protected",
    "upstream": {
      "preserve_host": true,
      "url": "http://host.docker.internal:80",
      "strip_path": "/api/account"
    },
    "match": {
      "url": "<(http|https):\\/\\/([\\w-]+(\\.[\\w-]+)*|[\\d.]+)(:\\d+)?\\/api\\/account(\\/.*)?>",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST" ,"PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"]
    },
    "authenticators": [{
      "handler": "cookie_session"
    }, {
      "handler": "oauth2_introspection"
    }, {
      "handler": "anonymous"
    }],
    "authorizer": {
      "handler": "allow"
    },
    "mutators": [{
      "handler": "id_token"
    }],
    "errors": [{
      "handler": "json"
    }]
  }
]
```

```
// oathkeeper.yml
serve:
  proxy:
    port: 4455 # run the proxy at port 4455
  api:
    port: 4456 # run the api at port 4456

access_rules:
  matching_strategy: regexp
  repositories:
    - file:///etc/config/oathkeeper/rules.json
    - file:///etc/config/oathkeeper/kratos.json

log:
  level: debug
  format: text
  leak_sensitive_values: true

errors:
  fallback:
    - json
  handlers:
    json:
      enabled: true
      config:
        verbose: true
    redirect:
      enabled: true
      config:
        to: https://www.ory.sh/docs

mutators:
  header:
    enabled: true
    config:
      headers:
        X-User: "{{ print .Subject }}"
  noop:
    enabled: true
  id_token:
    enabled: true
    config:
      issuer_url: http://localhost:4455/
      jwks_url: file:///etc/config/oathkeeper/jwks.json
      claims: '{"scope":"{{ .Extra.scope }}"}'

authorizers:
  allow:
    enabled: true
  deny:
    enabled: true
  remote_json:
    # remote_json documentation: https://www.ory.sh/oathkeeper/docs/pipeline/authz#remote_json
    enabled: true
    config:
      remote: http://keto:4466/check
      # must be set explicitly, otherwise: https://github.com/ory/oathkeeper/issues/797
      forward_response_headers_to_upstream: []
      payload: |
        {
            "namespace": "...",
            "subject": "...",
            "object": "...",
            "relation": "..."
        }

authenticators:
  noop:
    enabled: true
  cookie_session:
    enabled: true
    config:
      check_session_url: http://kratos:4433/sessions/whoami
      preserve_path: true
      extra_from: "@this"
      subject_from: "identity.id"
      only:
        - ory_kratos_session
  anonymous:
    enabled: true
    config:
      subject: guest
  oauth2_introspection:
    enabled: true
    config:
      introspection_url: http://hydra:4445/oauth2/introspect
```

I have tried to hardcode URLs into the config, but they don't appear to work either. If I use something like `http://localhost:4455/test` and I go to this URL in my browser, I get the same error.

The error response I get is provided below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "status": "Not Found",
    "message": "Requested url does not match any rules"
  }
}
```